# How to capture all videos in to be playable in video player script?

Tags: javascript, wistia

In the example below, I'm trying to capture all the videos in this script. However, I'm only able to capture the first video. I understand this has to do with `getElementById` and not `querySelectorAll`, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this script.

```js
var videoId = document.getElementById("wistia_video");
var uniqueVideoId = Array.from(videoId.classList)
  .find((c) => c.startsWith("wistia_async_"))
  .substring(13);
// console.log(uniqueVideoId);

const clickToPlay = document.querySelectorAll('.wistia')[0];

clickToPlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const playVideo = clickToPlay.querySelectorAll('.wistia__overlay, .embed-youtube__play');
  Array.from(playVideo).forEach((elem) => elem.remove());

  //supporting scripts
  let wistiaSupportScripts = [
    `https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js`,
    //adds jsonp file to provide security over requests
    `https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/${uniqueVideoId}.jsonp`
  ];

  //loads supporting scripts into head
  for (var i = 0; i < wistiaSupportScripts.length; i++) {
    let wistiaSupportScript = document.createElement("script");
    wistiaSupportScript.src = wistiaSupportScripts[i];
    let complete = false;
    if (!complete && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
      complete = true;
    }

    let wistiaContainers = document.querySelector(".wistia");

    wistiaContainers ? document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(wistiaSupportScript) : console.log("No Wistia videos here.");
  }

  window._wq = window._wq || [];
  _wq.push({
    //globally scoped
    id: uniqueVideoId,
    options: {
      autoPlay: true,
      volume: 0.5
    },

    onReady: function(video) {
      video.bind("play");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wistia {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wistia__overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wistia::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play {
  background: url("https://nextiva.com/assets/svg/play-button.svg") no-repeat center center, rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 55%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
  width: 10%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  max-height: 15%;    
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.wistia:hover button.embed-youtube__play,
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play:focus-visible,
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play:focus {
  background: url("https://nextiva.com/assets/svg/play-button.svg") no-repeat center center, #005fec;
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 55%;
}
.wistia_embed,
.wistia embed,
.wistia iframe {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net/deliveries/48f1d62d1ceddb4284ad9cf67c916235.jpg?auto=format&w=640" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net/deliveries/48f1d62d1ceddb4284ad9cf67c916235.jpg?auto=format&w=310" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <img src="https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net/deliveries/48f1d62d1ceddb4284ad9cf67c916235.jpg?auto=format&w=310" alt="some text" class="wistia__overlay lazy" loading="lazy">
  </picture>
  <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_vhkqhqhzyq videoFoam=true" id="wistia_video"></div>
  <button class="embed-youtube__play"></button>
</div>

<div class="wistia">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/2eab84ad71cf5acd9c7572d36667d255.jpg?auto=format&w=640" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/2eab84ad71cf5acd9c7572d36667d255.jpg?auto=format&w=310" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <img src="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/2eab84ad71cf5acd9c7572d36667d255.jpg?auto=format&w=310" alt="Some text" class="wistia__overlay lazy" loading="lazy">
  </picture>
  <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_8ei13wuby7 videoFoam=true" id="wistia_video"></div>
  <button class="embed-youtube__play"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture" the video? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I updated the question the best I could. When you click on the second video, it doesn't play. If you click on the first video, it plays. I'm trying to "capture" all the videos so that either one will play on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were only selecting the first `.wistia` block with this line:

`const clickToPlay = document.querySelectorAll('.wistia')[0];`

The other issue is the duplicated `id` as you noted, so that only the first video would be properly loaded. I have removed the `id` attribute entirely from the HTML, and updated the JS to properly loop over each `.wistia` div, attach a click handler, and then read the video ID from the associated child node.

The gist of the changes are:

```js
// Loop over every .wistia node and attach a click handler to each
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".wistia")).forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Read the video ID from within the current .wistia blocks children
    const videoId = getVideoId(node)

    // The rest is mostly how you had it before

  })
})
```

```js
const getVideoId = (ele) => {
  const classes = Array.from(ele.querySelector(".wistia_embed").classList);
  const idClass = classes.find((cls) => cls.startsWith("wistia_async_"));
  const id = idClass.replace("wistia_async_", "");

  return id;
};
const removeElems = (ele) => {
  const toRemove = Array.from(
ele.querySelectorAll(".wistia__overlay, .embed-youtube__play")
  );

  toRemove.forEach((node) => node.remove());
};

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".wistia")).forEach((node) => {
  node.addEventListener("click", () => {
const videoId = getVideoId(node);
let wistiaSupportScripts = [
  `https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js`,
  //adds jsonp file to provide security over requests
  `https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/${videoId}.jsonp`,
];

removeElems(node);

//loads supporting scripts into head
for (var i = 0; i < wistiaSupportScripts.length; i++) {
  let wistiaSupportScript = document.createElement("script");
  wistiaSupportScript.src = wistiaSupportScripts[i];
  let complete = false;
  if (
    !complete &&
    (!this.readyState ||
      this.readyState == "loaded" ||
      this.readyState == "complete")
  ) {
    complete = true;
  }

  let wistiaContainers = document.querySelector(".wistia");

  wistiaContainers
    ? document
        .getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
        .appendChild(wistiaSupportScript)
    : console.log("No Wistia videos here.");
}

window._wq = window._wq || [];
_wq.push({
  //globally scoped
  id: videoId,
  options: {
    autoPlay: true,
    volume: 0.5,
  },

  onReady: function (video) {
    video.bind("play");
  },
});
  });
});
```

```css
.wistia {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wistia__overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wistia::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play {
  background: url("https://nextiva.com/assets/svg/play-button.svg") no-repeat center center, rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 55%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
  width: 10%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  max-height: 15%;    
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.wistia:hover button.embed-youtube__play,
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play:focus-visible,
.wistia button.embed-youtube__play:focus {
  background: url("https://nextiva.com/assets/svg/play-button.svg") no-repeat center center, #005fec;
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position: 55%;
}
.wistia_embed,
.wistia embed,
.wistia iframe {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net/deliveries/48f1d62d1ceddb4284ad9cf67c916235.jpg?auto=format&w=640" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net/deliveries/48f1d62d1ceddb4284ad9cf67c916235.jpg?auto=format&w=310" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <img src="https://embedwistia-a.akamaihd.net/deliveries/48f1d62d1ceddb4284ad9cf67c916235.jpg?auto=format&w=310" alt="some text" class="wistia__overlay lazy" loading="lazy">
  </picture>
  <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_vhkqhqhzyq videoFoam=true"></div>
  <button class="embed-youtube__play"></button>
</div>

<div class="wistia">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/2eab84ad71cf5acd9c7572d36667d255.jpg?auto=format&w=640" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/2eab84ad71cf5acd9c7572d36667d255.jpg?auto=format&w=310" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <img src="https://embed-fastly.wistia.com/deliveries/2eab84ad71cf5acd9c7572d36667d255.jpg?auto=format&w=310" alt="Some text" class="wistia__overlay lazy" loading="lazy">
  </picture>
  <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_8ei13wuby7 videoFoam=true"></div>
  <button class="embed-youtube__play"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I was at the same position you're at, at one point. Run the code snippet in Full Page and you'll see the issue I'm running into. It seems like whichever video you click on, the other video gets doubled in the page.

Comment: You're just changing the question now. You wanted to know how to attach click handlers to each wistia node, not fix your CSS.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did 99% of this. I'm not asking for "coding service". My thought was that you would have tested this before submitting and you would have seen that.

Comment: How is anyone expected to know you aren't satisfied with the presentation if all you mention is problems with behavior? You should update your question to clearly state what you need help solving.

Comment: You are correct. I apologize for suggesting otherwise. This is on me. I got salty when I shouldn't have.